# Shaped charges and fluid dynamics

Tags: fluid-mechanics, design, product-testing

Watching this video https://twitter.com/Rainmaker1973/status/1713599092968787987 of objects being dropped into water and the resultant shape of the displaced fluid reminded me of videos showing how shaped charges work to destroy armour. Is there any relationship between the two, e.g. could the effectiveness of shaped charges be tested by dropping them into water and observing the shape of the displaced fluid?